# How do you integrate a curl operators?

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, curl

I have this proof that I need to do and I don't know how to execute a certain step.
The part that I don't get is this;
$$-\nabla \times E = \nabla \times (w \times B)$$
The notes just say, "Integrating we get";
$$E = (-w \times B) + (-\nabla \psi)$$
Where $-\nabla \psi$ is the constant of integration.

How do we integrate a curl operator? and what does that even mean?

Comment: When a curl is present, and you're told to integrate, that should be an invitation to use Stoke's theorem. Try integrating over a surface, seeing where it goes.

Comment: I like the approach but I have a problem with it,
How does integrating it along a surface remove the curl?
and if it does how do I choose what surface to integrate it along?
Sorry if I sound dumb I genuinely don't know what did they do.

Answer (score 6):

Here is one interpretation of what's going on. Noting that there is a curl on both sides, we can rewrite the equation as
$$
\nabla\times \left[w \times B + E \right] = 0.
$$
"Integrating" in this case seems to refer generically to undoing a differential operator, in this case the curl. It is known that if a vector field (over a simply connected domain) has curl zero, then it must be of the form $\nabla \phi$ for some scalar field $\phi$. Thus, we can write
$$
w \times B + E = \nabla \phi \implies E = -w \times B + \nabla \phi.
$$
Substituting $\psi = -\phi$ gives us the result from your notes.